# Power electrical engineering tags

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

We currently have a [power-distribution](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/power-distribution) and a [power-transmission](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/power-transmission) tag.

- [power-distribution](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/power-distribution) - 31 questions.

> Utility-scale power distribution, i.e. electricity grids, substations, overhead lines.

- [power-transmission](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/power-transmission) - 106 questions.

> High-voltage bulk power transmission over long distances of 100km or more. Usually at voltages 132kV, 220kV, 330kV and above. (For lower voltages such as 11kV, 22kV, 33kV, 66kV, see [power-distribution].)

I've three problems here:

1. 'Distribution' and 'transmission' overlap greatly, so I end up dual-tagging a lot of questions as both 'power-distribution' and 'power-transmission'.

   Example : `How do I interpret a current transformer class like "10 P150 F20"` would be a question in both `transmission` and `distribution`.
2. The number of questions in the `distribution` and `transmission` tags probably doesn't justify them being separate entities.
3. There's no tag to apply to power electrical things which are not transmission or distribution. Example: power electrical design, as in [Why are the letters U, V and W used in AC motors to represent the windings?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/195185/why-are-the-letters-u-v-and-w-used-in-ac-motors-to-represent-the-windings) .

---

**I would like to propose a new tag, [power-engineering](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/power-engineering)**.

This would supercede [power-distribution](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/power-distribution) and [power-transmission](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/power-transmission).

It would also cover power-electrical questions not previously included.

Proposed tag description:

> Power electrical engineering. Includes industrial electrical engineering (i.e. motors, switchboards), transmission and distribution (poles, wires, transformers, grids) and generation.

Comment: I am afraid this site is for Electronics Engineering, not for Electrical Engineering.

Comment: @hyprfrcb: Asserting that the site is about "Electronics engineering, not Electrical Engineering", is an interesting interpretation of the site banner, which says "Electrical Engineering Meta". It's right there in the name.

Comment: Yes it is in the name, but the current usage and focus is 95% electronics, as per their former names.

Answer (score 5):

This sounds reasonable to me, though I'll admit I don't have a ton of experience in the specific terminology to have  a strong opinion either way.

The proposed action would be:

1. The creation of the tag [power-engineering](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/power-engineering)
2. Merge [power-distribuion](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/power-distribuion) into [power-engineering](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/power-engineering) and make it a synonym
3. Merge [power-transmission](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/power-transmission) into [power-engineering](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/power-engineering) and make it a synonym
4. Add the [power-engineering](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/power-engineering) tag to valid questions.

---

One note: I don't see your point #2 (low number of posts) as a good justification by itself when there's 30 or so questions. If there is value in distinguishing between [power-distribution](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/power-distribution) and [power-transmission](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/power-transmission), I would rather keep them separate.

Comment: I would argue that the boundary between [tag:power-distribution] and [tag:power-transmission] is so blurry that it's hard to tell which is which. Aside from the physical size of the equipment, they have much more in common than differences.

Comment: @Li-aungYip go ahead and make the tag, and then I'll do the rest.

Comment: I've created a tag and put in a tag description for approval. Thanks.

Comment: @Li-aungYip: I'm afraid this change didn't help much. People just can't find/think of this tag. I've added it to a bunch of questions, but realistically, I can't see people new to the site being able to discover it on their own.

Comment: @RespawnedFluff I don't think that *finding* the tag was a goal of this action. Note that since these are all *synonyms*, they'll still show up just the same.

Comment: Agree with @W5VO, people typing "transmission" in the tags box will have "power-engineering" suggested to them. The system works.